# How to pass List<int> to kendo grid read()

Tags: list, parameters, kendo-grid

I just want to pass list of integer values to read() method.

used "parameterMap" to map parameter. also tried to set data object.

```
transport: {
                    read: {
                        url:
                            "@Url.HttpRouteUrl("ActionApi", new {controller = "Regions",action = "GetByCountries" })",
                        //dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        debugger;
                        if (operation === "read") {
                            return { countries: selectedCountries};
                        }
                    }
                },
```

my Controller like bellow

```
    [System.Web.Http.ActionName("GetByCountries")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public List<Region> GetByCountries(List<int> countries)
    {
        return new RegionMgt().GetByCountries(countries).ToList());
    }
```

gives null value for countries parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This Work for me :)

```
transport: {

                    read: function(options) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "@Url.HttpRouteUrl("ActionApi", new { controller = "Regions", action = "GetByCountries" })",
                            data: JSON.stringify(selectedCountries),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (result) {
                                options.success(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
```

Hope anyone help...!